# Surefire Report not generating on Script Error

Tags: maven, selenium, surefire

I have a couple simple tests that looks like this.

```
public class My1Test extends AutoBaseFunctions{

@Test
public void test1(){

    startDriver(STARTPAGE,DRIVER2USE);
    schoolLogin("XXX", "XXX");

    toolbarNav("toolsSingle","Manage Users");

    getElmObject("input[type='checkbox'][name='includeUsersHiddenFromDirectory']",loctype.CSS).click();
    getElmObject("Searchxx",loctype.LINKTEXT).click();

    driver.quit();
    //driver.close();
}
```

}

The problem I have is this: I am purposely causing a NoSuchElement Exception to happen when doing a findElement on the search button. When I run the  mvn surefire-report:report command the output stops here

[image: surefire report output]

until I MANUALLY close the window that was opened - only then does it finish generating the report.

I understand that when the script errors out it dies and never gets to the driver.quit line. But, if I put it in a try/catch block, the report shows the test as passed and doesn't report the error details. I also tried putting this as part of a @Suite test and using @After/@AfterClass but that doesn't close the driver window either.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the report to generate after an error is encountered without having to "be present" to manually close the open windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it in try/catch and in catch block do

```
    try{

    }catch(Exception e){
     Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
              // CLOSE ANY OPEN RESOURCES HERE !!!!
    }
```

If you have any open resources, don't forget to close them in finally block.

Comment: TY for your reply - I tried doing this: `try{
       getElmObject("Searchxx",loctype.LINKTEXT).click();
       }catch (Exception e){
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
            //driver.quit();
            }` but got the same outcome - the only difference is the error is reported as a failure instead of an error - I still have to manually click the X to close the driver window before surefire completes the report

Comment: @Aces'nEights any open resources? which you may have to release/close in finally block ?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - still learning Java and completely forgot about the 'finally' block. By moving the driver.quit into the finally block - it closes my window and completes the report generation - TYVM